# gulp-jade reports error like 'Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined'

Tags: node.js, gulp, pug

When i use gulp-jade@1.1.0 to compile the "index.jade"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
html(lang="en")
head
    meta(charset="UTF-8")
    title Document
body
    - var json = {'foo': 'bar'}
    include template
```

including the "template.jade"

```
h1= json.foo
```

gulp-jade always report the error like

```
[15:11:34] Starting 'jade'...
[15:11:34] Starting 'sass'...
[15:11:34] Finished 'sass' after 2.68 ms
[15:11:34] Plumber found unhandled error:
 TypeError in plugin 'gulp-jade'
Message:
    C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\workspace\node\src\jade\template.jade:1
  > 1| h1= json.foo

Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined
Details:
    path: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\workspace\node\src\jade\template.jade
[15:11:34] Finished 'jade' after 19 ms
```

But html file after compiling is right

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"></html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>bar</h1>
</body>
```

And my gulpfile write like this

```
gulp.task('jade', function(){
    return gulp.src('src/jade/*.jade')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(gulpJade({
            jade: jade,
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/html'))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Gulp trying to compile each template separately.

You must specify only entry-point (*index.jade*) instead:

```
gulp.task('jade', function(){
    return gulp.src('src/jade/index.jade')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(gulpJade({
            jade: jade,
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/html'))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

or exclude *template.jade* from *gulp.src*